# Is it possible, for each closed set $E$, to an $f$ which is 0 precisely on E and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^1$. Is it possible, for each closed set $E$, to an $f$ which is 0 precisely on E and differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^1$, or one which is $n$ times differentiable, or even one which has derivatives of all orders on $\mathbb{R}^1$?

My approach is following:
Since $E^c$ is open.
So, $E^c$ can be covered by open intervals.

Now, $(a,b)$ be an open interval.
We define $f$ such that $f$ is $0$ on $E$.
On $(a,b)$ we define as $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{(x-a)^2}}$ on $a<x\le\frac{a+b}{2}$ and then we take it's reflection about the line $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$.
If $a$ is $-\infty$ then we define $f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{(x-b)^2}},x<b$ and similarly for the other infinite cases.

Is it a correct approach?

Comment: Wouldn't the graph of your $f$ have a "corner" at $x=(a+b)/2$, where it is Lipschitz but not differentiable?

Comment: I think your idea is excellent, except for a minor technical detail: at the point $x=\frac{a+b}{2}$ the function will most likely not be differentiable at all, and will have some sort of a spike. I think you need to stitch those two bits together in a more smooth manner.

Comment: Given $E \subseteq {\mathbb R},$ it's a fairly standard result that $E$ is closed if and only if there exists $f: {\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ such that $f$ is infinitely differentiable and $f^{-1}(0) = E.$ See [Can Cantor set be the zero set of a continuous function?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24034/15780) *AND* [Non-zero smooth functions vanishing on a Cantor set](https://mathoverflow.net/q/179445/15780)